# How to take back directory permission granted to a user?

Tags: linux, permissions, sftp

I was setting up a sftp server and have given permission to the root directory to a user by mistake. Due to which I am getting following error:

```
sftp sshd[5234]: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
```

Here is how permission is on the root directory:

```
ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 23 user_other_than_root ftpaccess 4096 Jul 30 05:29 /
```

How do I remove this permission? Due to this my sftp server has stopped working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *permissions* are `drwxr-xr-x` which seems correct, but you have **changed the owner** of the directory. Now, there are two possibilities:

1. If you only have changed the owner for this single directory, you should be able to revert it using:

   ```
   sudo chown root:root /
   ```
2. If you have done this *recursively*, you have messed up your whole server and need to build it from scratch i.e. reinstall and recover from backups.